# Rails link_to with params and anchor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have the following `link_to` on my products index page, which essentially reloads the current page with a `:tag` parameter. This works just fine. However, when I include an `anchor` attribute, the page no longer reloads, the user is just taken to the anchor within the page (the page does not reload with the given `:tag` param)

```
<%=  link_to('Foo',
          products_path(:tag => 'bar', anchor: 'foo-anchor'),
          class: 'btn black-btn')
%>
```

When I inspect the link, the `href` looks like `domain.com/products?tag=bar#foo-anchor`. This seems fine, however because I think I'm already on domain.com/products the page does not refresh, it only takes you to the anchor. How can I get the page to reload with the given `param`, and THEN take the user to the anchor?

Comment: what do u mean is not refreshed ? It should just go products page.

Comment: This link is on the products page. So yes, clicking it will should take you to the products page. Or in other words, reload the current page with the given params.

Answer (score 1):

This is how HTML links work. If you have a link that leads to an anchor on the current page, the page won't reload, just scroll to the anchor position. If you want to force the page to reload, you may call `window.location.reload();` when the link is clicked - e.g. add some class to the link and add a click handler like this:

```
$('a.force-reload').on('click', function(){ 
  window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
  window.location.reload();
});
```